# How do I replicate Daz3D Iray skin shading in Blender EEVEE?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine, import

I am trying to replicate this skin rendered with Iray:

[image: Iray skin render]

Notice the smooth yet defined skin and features, as well as the subsurface scattering, particularly under the eyes and mouth.

This is how I was able to make it look in EEVEE:

[image: EEVEE skin render]

([.blend file download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tj9sybwh84yjkh/DefaultMan.blend?dl=0))

Not too bad, but a lot of the detail is gone. I have enabled subsurface translucency under the material settings and tweaked the shader. Unfortunately, the more I change, the worse it gets. For example, increasing the Subsurface value makes the skin look blurry. Finally, there is this blue outline where the face borders on the plane below. As far as I know, there is no workaround for that. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Here are the material nodes:

[image: Material nodes 1]
[image: Material nodes 2]
[image: Material nodes 3]

How do I make the skin look more similar to the Iray render?